# Would an automatic bleeder resolve condo heat problems?

Tags: valve, baseboard, heat, air

Please bear with me as I am trying to help a senior citizen with no heat for over a week in NJ. She lives in an old (built 1966) multiple unit apartment condo where each unit is individually owned.

There is one commercial size boiler providing heat to 36 apartment units (baseboard heat with water). For over a month now the maintenance man sent by HOA has been bleeding (releasing air) in the system in the basement (she has no access to that area). The heat has been on for few days then off again for like a month, however for past week the heat has not come on. Only her and another neighbor (next door, both on 2nd floor) have the issue of the 36 total.

The neighbor got fed up with the HOA not fixing the issue permanently, hired a plumber who installed what I understand to be an air bleeder valve inside the apartment. See picture below. Now (it has been 5 days) the neighbor has heat. HOA tells the senior citizen that since the fix is to be done inside the apartment then as per rules she is responsible for hiring a plumber to do it. The plumber neighbor hired is expensive. I found a less pricey one BUT he says he can install an AUTOMATIC BLEEDING VALVE.

Is the automatic bleeding valve as good as what you see in the picture or perhaps it is not strong enough and there is a possibility it will not purge the air from such a large system?

[image]

Comment: does anything come out when you open the blue valve?

Comment: The pic is of the neighbors heating system, not the system in question.

Comment: Is the person on the top floor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "bleeder" that is shown with the blue handle is nothing more than a hose bib. I would suspect that an automatic bleeder would be as good or better.

As to an answer for your question of "would an automatic bleeder resolve condo heat problems"  Yes it should.  The greatest possible reason for no heat from a register is air trapped.  The bleeder will correct that issue.  That should be further proven since the neighbor has had heat restored since the air was bled off.

Laws differ from state to state. However in Fla that has many condos, the laws make it the responsibility of the association to maintain any system that was originally part of construction when common to the building. If the boiler supplies heat to the entire building and the heaters in the apartments are original to the system, the condo association should be responsible to make the system work as originally intended **for all owners.**

When an owner changes parts of the system,
( Installs new registers or modifies the system in any way.) the responsibility to maintain that part is turned to the owner and any subsequent owner.  This can make things sticky when that isn't relayed to new owners.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Where we had a hard time understanding is that if the system was bled in the basement why has it stopped "fixing" the issue. The maintenance man has bled it in the basement for 3 or 4 times since mid Dec and then his actions no longer worked. I am thinking - is it possible (perhaps unlikely but possible ) that the air is somehow stuck high on 2nd floor and the bleeding of the system in the basement just doesn't fully clear all the air? Maintenance man said he bled it for 15 minutes.

Comment: The bleeding should be done from the highest points, ( your apartment).   If the maintenance man is bleeding in the basement and he is getting great amounts of air and often, then there is a problem that must be identified and repaired,  I am not an expert on boiler systems so I''l leave that for those who are. I do remember some of my first maintenance tasks were bleeding registers in apartments my father owned , to get people heat.  It always worked...I was only 12.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I have a rather simple follow up question - just to make it all make sense to a lame person as myself :-)  Is there a possibility in which an air trapped in the pipes is not able to be released by the means of bleeding valves? In other words is there a situation in which the valve would not solve the "no heat" issue if we assume that air trapped in the system is the culprit.?

Comment: @MonCia,   There is a low possibility that air cannot be released by a bleeding valve. However that would have to be the result of the valve being in the wrong location.  An experienced plumbing or HVAC person should know where as well as how to install a bleeder valve.  The simple reason you cannot get heat from the register is that there is air that will not allow the water to enter the unit. Once the air is removed the hot water comes in and releases it's heat.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out.